# gvisColumnChart - blank space between column plot

Tags: r, googlevis

I am plotting gvisColumnChart, my x-axis data is Date-Time variable and I don't have data for some Date-Time, gvisColumnChart is showing blank space in between. How should I remove this space and plot continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert Date-Time variable to character, df$Column_Name = as.character(df$Column_Name)